# How to re-write count-up loop with system.out in stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I rewrite this code in Java 8 stream API?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("001", "007", "012", "099", "101", "167");
    int total = 0;
    for (String id : ids) {
        if (id.indexOf("1") >= 0) {
            System.out.println(id);
            total++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total count: " + total);
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it like :

```
    System.out.println(
            "Total count: " + ids.stream()
                                .filter(id -> id.indexOf("1") >= 0)
                                .peek(System.out::println)
                                 .count());
```

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent stream can be like so :

```
long total = ids.stream()
     .filter(id - > id.indexOf("1") >= 0)
     .peek(System.out::println)
     .count();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fastest answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

It might be even simpler:

```
long count = Arrays.stream(new String[] {"001", "007", "012", "099", "101", "167"})
                   .filter(id -> id.contains("1"))
                   .peek(System.out::println)
                   .count();
```

I'd rather have a short break with the condition. The statement `id -> id.indexOf("1") >= 0` means that the `"1"` is contained in the given string at **any** position, therefore the following expression using [`String::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) would me more suitable:

```
.filter(id -> id.contains("1"))
```

On the other hand, I feel you might want to count these ids having `"1"` at the **first** position, therefore [`String::startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) is better:

```
.filter(id -> id.startsWith("1"))
```

In any case, you have your answer already here.